# How can I view a selected item in detailpage using angularjs factory $http and $stateParameters

Tags: angularjs

Here is mij code but data is hardcoded and working perfect. When I try my data  dynamicly calling data responsed good. My question is look this script with hardcoded data. If i will selected item viewing in detailpage working nice.

Shortly this hardcoded data must from webmethod. How can I do it?

This is my html code for view menu as list;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Menu
            </li>
        </ol>

        <div class="row" ng-controller="DesktopController">         
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h2>Menu Lijst</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>ParentID</th>
                                <th>Parent</th>
                                <th>MenuItem ID</th>
                                <th>Index</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="menu in List" style="width:auto;">                              

                                <td>{{menu.Description}}</td>  
                                <td>{{menu.State}}</td>
                                <td>{{menu.ParentID}}</td>
                                <td>{{menu.Parent}}
                                </td>
                                <td>{{menu.MenuItemID}}</td> 
                                <td>{{$index}}</td> 
                                <td>
                                <a href="#/menuDetail/{{$index}}" class="btn btn-info">View Detail</a>
                                </td>                           
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my detail menu view page...

```
    <h1>View DetailMenu Page</h1>
    <br />
    <!--<h1>{{menu.Description}}</h1>-->
<div class="row" ng-controller="viewDetailMenuController">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>{{menu.Description}}</h2>

    </div>
</div>

App.factory('menuService', function ($http) {
```

var obj = {
        getAllMenus: [{ "ID": "1", "Description": "MOTOR", "State": "1", "ParentID": "0", "Parent": "", "MenuItemID": "0" }, { "ID": "2", "Description": "FILTERS", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "1" }, { "ID": "3", "Description": "BRANDSTOF/TANKDOPPEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "2" }, { "ID": "4", "Description": "ONSTEKING", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "3" }, { "ID": "5", "Description": "ACCU/STARTEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "4" }, { "ID": "6", "Description": "BOUGIES/BOUGIEKABELS", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "5" }, { "ID": "7", "Description": "D-RIEMEN/V-REIM-SETS", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "6" }, { "ID": "8", "Description": "PAKKINGEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "7" }, { "ID": "9", "Description": "MOTORBLOK", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "8" }, { "ID": "10", "Description": "CYLINDERKOP", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "9" }, { "ID": "11", "Description": "MOTORMANAGEMENT", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "10" }, { "ID": "12", "Description": "UITLATEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "1", "Parent": "MOTOR", "MenuItemID": "11" }, { "ID": "13", "Description": "KOELING", "State": "2", "ParentID": "0", "Parent": "", "MenuItemID": "12" }, { "ID": "14", "Description": "AIRCO", "State": "0", "ParentID": "13", "Parent": "KOELING", "MenuItemID": "13" }, { "ID": "15", "Description": "KOELSYSTEEM/WATERPOMP", "State": "0", "ParentID": "13", "Parent": "KOELING", "MenuItemID": "14" }, { "ID": "16", "Description": "SCHAKELAARS/SENSOREN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "13", "Parent": "KOELING", "MenuItemID": "15" }, { "ID": "17", "Description": "SLANGEN/LEIDINGEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "13", "Parent": "KOELING", "MenuItemID": "16" }, { "ID": "18", "Description": "ONDERSTEL", "State": "1", "ParentID": "0", "Parent": "", "MenuItemID": "17" }, { "ID": "19", "Description": "STUURDELEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "18" }, { "ID": "20", "Description": "KABELS", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "19" }, { "ID": "21", "Description": "AANDRIJVING/HOEAEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "20" }, { "ID": "22", "Description": "KOPPELING", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "21" }, { "ID": "23", "Description": "WIELLAGERS", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "22" }, { "ID": "24", "Description": "SCHOKDEMPERS", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "23" }, { "ID": "25", "Description": "VEREN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "24" }, { "ID": "26", "Description": "TREKHAAK", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "25" }, { "ID": "27", "Description": "BANDEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "19", "Parent": "STUURDELEN", "MenuItemID": "26" }, { "ID": "28", "Description": "REMDELEN NAT/DROOG", "State": "2", "ParentID": "0", "Parent": "", "MenuItemID": "27" }, { "ID": "29", "Description": "REM-DELEN/SCHIJVEN", "State": "0", "ParentID": "28", "Parent": "REMDELEN NAT/DROOG", "MenuItemID": "28" }]
    }

```
return obj;
```

});

Controllers:

```
var App = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);

App.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'Pages/Home.html'
        })
        .state('menu', {
            url: '/menu',
            templateUrl: 'Pages/Menu.html'
        })
      .state('menuDetail', {
          url: '/menuDetail/{id}',
          templateUrl: 'Pages/MenuDetail.html',
          controller: 'viewDetailMenuController'
      });

});

App.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});

App.controller("DesktopController",  function ($scope, menuService) {

    $scope.List = menuService.getAllMenus;

});

App.controller("viewDetailMenuController", function ($scope, menuService, $stateParams) {

    $scope.menu = menuService.getAllMenus[$stateParams.id];

});
```

This work perfect. Only my question is how can I do that selected menu view in detail page using $http $stateParams (dynamic data calling from webservice or webmethod)?

Before this question I have shared calling data from webmethod you can see it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

write this code

```
 .state('menuDetail', {
          url: '/menuDetail/:id',
          templateUrl: 'Pages/MenuDetail.html',
          controller: 'viewDetailMenuController'
      });

<a ui-sref="menuDetail({ id: dynamicId })">Click</a>
```

and when you click on 'Click' then open detail page

For more know https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference

Comment: Dear Jain, Thanks your answer. Shared codes work perfect my question is on place hardcode I'll dynamic data. example:   var urlBase = 'Services/MenuService.asmx/GetAllMenu/ID=';
    var factory = {};
    factory.getAllMenus= function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    } return factory; }); With this code response data good. In controller I want a select an item and selected item in the list I'll view in another page.

Comment: When I call data dynamicly viewed with this code all the list. It's OK.  App.controller("DesktopController",  function ($scope, menuService) {
  

    var menuData=function(data, status){
        $scope.List = data;

        console.log($scope.List);
    }

   menuService.getAllMenus().success(menuData);
});   But another controller how can i select an item in the list? By hardcode I can call it so: App.controller("viewDetailMenuController", function ($scope, menuService, $stateParams) {
  
    $scope.menu = menuService.getAllMenus[$stateParams.id];
  // Hardcoded data
});

Comment: you want to show menu list in all pages and Detail page will change according to menu (dynamically)?

Comment: Yes I want show menuList in menu page and will change according to menu (dynamicly) in detailpage.

Comment: Because on menu page we load all menulist.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to get your menu items from server instead of hardcoding.

```
App.factory('menuService', function ($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getAllMenus = function(){
        return $http.get('url_or_your_webapi');//this returns a promise
    }; 

    return service;
});
```

then we need to get that menu data in controller:

```
App.controller("DesktopController",  function ($scope, menuService) {
    // here we set callback for promise we received from our menu service
    menuService.getAllMenus().then(function(response){$scope.List = response.data;});
});
```

***UPD*** menu service code fixed, now returns function

Comment: yes, there was mistake in menuService, now should be fine